# Get my android app download status

Tags: android, google-play

I am new to android development. Recently I have uploaded an android app using my Google Play Android Developer Console and now my app is in Google Play.

I have downloaded my app from Google play store and installed  it in my mobile.

But when I checked the download statics in Developer Console (information found near to my app in dev console), it stated:

```
0 total user installs
0 active device installs
```

Can anyone please say me why is this so? I have downloaded and installed my app from Google play store. So it must show the count as 1. But still it displays the count as 0.

Am I checking the count in a wrong place? Is there any other tool or Google place to check and get my app downloads and installed information?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fear not, the delayed count is not your fault. Google Play download statistics are uploaded once every 24 hours (approximately).

From [*Google Play for Developers*](http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139628):

> These statistics are refreshed on a daily basis at 12:00 am PST.

Despite what it says, I find they update more around 9:00 am PST, though it varies greatly. (There have been cases of severely delayed download stats, but this usually happens to *everyone* and a notice is displayed on the console.)

Comment: Thanks Eric.. Are you aware of any third party tools to get my app downloads/installation information. The reason for this question is, I like to view my app download statics immediately (for every app downloads and installation). Not sure whether its possible. Your thoughts on this? Thank you again..

Comment: I'm not too familiar with libraries such as this. However, if I had to guess, I would say [use Google's Analytics library](http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2010/12/analytics-for-android-apps.html), then register a custom event on *first launch*, then set some `SharedPreferences` setting that says "not first launch anymore". Keep in mind, if someone reinstalls your app or wipes its data, you may get skewed stats. I know of no further way to assist that.

Comment: Having recently (Feb 2014) published a new app, it took as long as 48 hours before any install statistics were available for it in Play Developer Console.